# Spring Security and ACL, DataSource required

Tags: java, spring-security, acl

I'm trying to get Spring Security ACL working. I followed the instructions at http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-acl but it's not working. I'm getting

```
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'aclMethodSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setMethodSecurityExpressionHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler' defined in class path resource [com/xyz/timetracker/config/AclMethodSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'aclMethodSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclService' defined in class path resource [com/xyz/timetracker/config/AclMethodSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'aclMethodSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'aclService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lookupStrategy' defined in class path resource [com/xyz/timetracker/config/AclMethodSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.LookupStrategy]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'aclMethodSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'lookupStrategy' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:497) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:238) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:709) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.xyz.timetracker.TimetrackerApplication.main(TimetrackerApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'aclMethodSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setMethodSecurityExpressionHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler' defined in class path resource [com/xyz/timetracker/config/AclMethodSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'aclMethodSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclService' defined in class path resource [com/xyz/timetracker/config/AclMethodSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'aclMethodSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'aclService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lookupStrategy' defined in class path resource [com/xyz/timetracker/config/AclMethodSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.LookupStrategy]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'aclMethodSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'lookupStrategy' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:94) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:107) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:254) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1063) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'aclMethodSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setMethodSecurityExpressionHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler' defined in class path resource [com/xyz/timetracker/config/AclMethodSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'aclMethodSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aclService' defined in class path resource [com/xyz/timetracker/config/AclMethodSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'aclMethodSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'aclService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lookupStrategy' defined in class path resource [com/xyz/timetracker/config/AclMethodSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.LookupStrategy]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'aclMethodSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'lookupStrategy' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required

... <A bunch of stuff omitted because of character limit> ...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.LookupStrategy]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'aclMethodSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'lookupStrategy' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 113 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy.<init>(BasicLookupStrategy.java:165) ~[spring-security-acl-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy.<init>(BasicLookupStrategy.java:150) ~[spring-security-acl-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.xyz.timetracker.config.AclMethodSecurityConfig.lookupStrategy(AclMethodSecurityConfig.java:98) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.xyz.timetracker.config.AclMethodSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d507e868.CGLIB$lookupStrategy$3(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.xyz.timetracker.config.AclMethodSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d507e868$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cc32f895.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.xyz.timetracker.config.AclMethodSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d507e868.lookupStrategy(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 114 common frames omitted
```

My AclMethodSecurityConfig.java is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class AclMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    MethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;

    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        AclPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator = new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService());
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
        return expressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcMutableAclService aclService() {
        return new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource, lookupStrategy(), aclCache());
    }

    @Bean
    public AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy() {
        return new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }

    @Bean
    public PermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy() {
        return new DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(new ConsoleAuditLogger());
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheBasedAclCache aclCache() {
        return new EhCacheBasedAclCache(
                aclEhCacheFactoryBean().getObject(),
                permissionGrantingStrategy(),
                aclAuthorizationStrategy()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheFactoryBean aclEhCacheFactoryBean() {
        EhCacheFactoryBean ehCacheFactoryBean = new EhCacheFactoryBean();
        ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheManager(aclCacheManager().getObject());
        ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheName("aclCache");
        return ehCacheFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean aclCacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public LookupStrategy lookupStrategy() {
        return new BasicLookupStrategy(
                dataSource,
                aclCache(),
                aclAuthorizationStrategy(),
                new ConsoleAuditLogger()
        );
    }
}
```

I set the datasource that way after reading [Group and acl on Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920959/group-and-acl-on-spring-security) that but it still doesn't work.
I added the dependencies to my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that separating the AclMethodSecurityConfig file into 2 files fixed the problem.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class AclMethodSecurityConfiguration extends 
GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    MethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }

}
```

And everything else went into an ACLContext class

Comment: Nice. Looks like the problem is something to do with a circular reference between the ``aclService()`` method and the ``AclMethodSecurityConfiguration`` configuration class itself. The configuration class appears to be a bean itself, and so deep down in Spring ACL maybe that configuration bean is getting injected into something that ``aclService()`` needs, hence the loop. Would be nice to know what that something is that's causing the loop, but then again, the fix works so that's the main thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to Autowire datasource. Also reported on console log

> Nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required

Try to autowire datasource in AclMethodSecurityConfig

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
```

Comment: He has not missed `@Autowired`, He has done @Autowired on `setDataSource` method.